# uploading binary file in android

Tags: android, image, upload

i have been trying all day to upload a binary file (image) to a server with every library i know about, mainly OKHTTP and for some reason i always get a timeout or refused... i would be glad if someone here could point me in the right direction, i even tried using android-upload-service if i use a multipart upload it works but the file will become a gibberish text file and if i use a binaryupload it just wont work.

snippet from the last one :

```
String uploadId =
                    new BinaryUploadRequest(context, serverURL)
                    .setFileToUpload(file.getAbsolutePath())
                    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .startUpload();
```

thanks for the help!